# nginx plus with proxy_next_upstream directive doesnt work

Tags: nginx, ibm-cloud, load-balancing, failover

Problem Statement:
I want to setup a active failover using nginx plus ( i subscribed for 30 day trial).
All servers should go to primary server, if that goes down(404) only then the requests should go to second server. Once the primary is up the requests should go back to the original server. Is it possible?
With the help of other threads i was able to create the following config file. Almost all the error codes i could find, I tried that with proxy_next_upstream, but i am still not able to achieve the intended results.

I brought down the primary server manually to return 404. It briefly return 503 when its going down. But still no luck with redirecting the traffic.
Both the servers are hosted on IBM Bluemix as nodejs apps. I can share more details if needed.

```
upstream up1 {
   server up_server1;
}

upstream up2 {

server up_server2;

}


server {
   listen 80;

   location / {

 proxy_pass http://up1;
         proxy_next_upstream non_idempotent invalid_header error timeout http_500 http_502 http_504 http_403 http_404;
   }
}
```

This is governed by another config file which looks like. Just to give more info

```
    user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
#    geoip_city         /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


# TCP/UDP proxy and load balancing block
#
#stream {
    # Example configuration for TCP load balancing

    #upstream stream_backend {
    #    zone tcp_servers 64k;
    #    server backend1.example.com:12345;
    #    server backend2.example.com:12345;
    #}

    #server {
    #    listen 12345;
    #    status_zone tcp_server;
    #    proxy_pass stream_backend;
    #}
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do not in any way use the `upstream up2`. `proxy_next_upstream` mean next server in your current upstream - which is defined as "up1" in `proxy_pass http://up1`, not magically pick any other upstream.

So what you want is to delete `upstream up2` and only leave:

```
upstream up1 {
   server up_server1;
   server up_server2;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was able to resolve this issue with a small tweak, which was missed in almost all the answers posted in stack overflow. When you are defining 2 different upstreams for using with proxy_next_upstream, you need to add the server as a second entry in your original upstream directive. Check out the code below.

```
upstream up1 {
   server up_server1;
   server up_server2; # this entry is important, but not sure why!
}

upstream up2 {

server up_server2;

}
```